# Finding maximum area k-gon given a set of points

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I posted this question on stackoverflow and was redirected here, as this was a mathematical problem.

I was trying to solve a practice problem in the topcoder arena: http://topcoder.bgcoder.com/print.php?id=417

According to my understanding the aim of the problem is to find a $k$-gon of maximum area, given a set of Points $D$ and $k\leq n$, $n$ is a fixed value.

Let the Convex Hull of $D$ = $C(D)$

If $n=3$, i have proved that such a triangle can be constructed by assuming that it's vertices are a subset of $C(D)$.
So it was quite easy to come up with a solution for $k=3$ : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621913/4126652

However, for n>3, i have no idea how to do this.
Can anyone help solving the problem?

Here is how i tried:

Let $|C(D)| = l$ i.e the convex hull is an $l$-gon,

If $n > l$ the $k$-gon with maximum area will be the convex hull itself, i.e $C(D)$

if $n < l$ i am pretty sure that the vertices of the maximal k-gon will be a subset of C(D), i couldn't prove it for $k>3$, and i am unable to come up with an algorithm to solve even if this is a correct assumption.

Comment: Interesting question. I am pretty sure your conjecture is right - vertices will be vertices of the convex hull. Possible (greedy) algorithm: find the biggest triangle. Then for each edge of the polygon-so-far add the vertex of the convex hull between the endpoints of that edge (if any) that maximizes the area of the new triangle.

Comment: @EthanBolker this was my first thought too, but this solution gives wrong answer for the following set of Points, {(0,4), (1,7), (4,8), (7,7), (8,4), (7,1), (4,0), (1,1)}. The largest triangle would be at v2, v4 and v7 but the largest quadrilateral would be a square formed by v2, v4, v6 and v8. which does not involve v7 at all.

Comment: Well we both had the same first wrong idea. Here's another. While you have more vertices than you want, delete the vertex that creates the smallest triangle with its two adjacent vertices. (I haven't checked this even on your counterexample.)  Good luck.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.11035 Maximum-Area Triangle in a Convex Polygon, Revisited   Given a convex polygon P, find the largest-area inscribed triangle. We show by example that the linear-time algorithm presented in 1979 by Dobkin and Snyder for solving this problem fails. We then proceed to show that with a small adaptation, their approach does lead to a quadratic-time algorithm.  Also we show by example that the algorithm presented in 1979 by Dobkin and Snyder for finding the largest-area k-gon that is inscribed in a convex polygon fails to find the optimal solution for k=4.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00681  Given a convex polygon P, find the largest-area inscribed triangle. We show by example that the linear-time algorithm presented in 1979 by Dobkin and Snyder for solving this problem fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After breaking my head for a few hours, i figured out the solution.

It is a dynamic programming problem:

Let $dp(m,o,r)$ denote the maximum area $r$-gon such that the starting vertex is $m$ and the ending vertex is $o$.

Then recurrence relation will be:

$dp(m,o,r) = \max\limits_{\forall n: \lbrace m<n<o \rbrace} (dp(m,n,r-1) + area(m,n,o))$

where $area(m,n,o)$ is the area of the triangle formed by vertices $m$,$n$ and $o$